# How do I upload a completely new app that replaces and older existing version in a device for users?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I currently have app A pushed out in the market. 
I build app B completely new from the ground up. 
How do I provide users of App A a seamless transition from A to B? 
The expectation is to treat it like an update instead of a fresh install.
Anyone have a step by step solution?

Comment: just upload it as new version of App A

Answer (score 1):

you can change completely  your app look and behavior, so long as u maintain the package name of the already published APK and the new APP.  changing the package name means ur publishing  new APP

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a new app with the same bundle as your older app.

For example, **com.abc.app**

Then, also you will need to sign the application with the same keyStore as the previous one.